# Aspose.Pdf.TextStamp overlaps with the previously added text. How is it possible to prevent this?

Tags: .net, pdf, constructor, pagination, aspose

**Aspose.Pdf.TextStamp** overlaps with the previously added text. How is it possible to prevent this?

Here is the code I am using to prepare a document:

```
 StringBuilder htmlPage = new StringBuilder();
 //put here the html from https://pastebin.com/c6Hu4nV5 
 //instead of the `text foo`
 htmlPage.Append("text foo"); 
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlPage.ToString());
 var streamHtml = new MemoryStream(bytes)
 var objLoadOptions = new Aspose.Pdf.HtmlLoadOptions(0, 50, 0, 0);
 var doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(streamHtml, objLoadOptions);
```

Here is the code I am using for the page numbers (which are stamps in my context) addition:

```
foreach (var page in doc.Pages)
{
    Aspose.Pdf.Facades.FormattedText formattedText = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.FormattedText(idAndVersion + page.Number + "-" + doc.Pages.Count,
                            Color.Black, Aspose.Pdf.Facades.FontStyle.Helvetica, Aspose.Pdf.Facades.EncodingType.Identity_h,
                            true, 12F);
    var textStamp = new Aspose.Pdf.TextStamp(formattedText)
    {
        VerticalAlignment = Aspose.Pdf.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
        HorizontalAlignment = Aspose.Pdf.HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        LeftMargin = 50,
        BottomMargin = 20
    };
    page.AddStamp(textStamp);
}
```

I am using the stamps as a way of adding page numbers. Maybe there is a better way to do it?

I tried to find a better way over [here](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/pdf), but with no success.

After I add the page numbers, here is what I do:

```
using (var streamPdf = new MemoryStream())
{
    doc.Save(streamPdf, Aspose.Pdf.SaveFormat.Pdf);
    return streamPdf.GetBuffer();
}
```

[image]

Comment: would you kindly share your PDF document on which you are trying to add text stamps by uploading it to Google Drive or Dropbox. We will test the scenario in our environment and address it accordingly. I am Asad Ali and I work at Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AsadAli, I am generating the file content and creating a file at runtime as you can see above. Meaning that I do not have a file when the code related to the pdf generation starts to execute. Would you like me to provide you with the string content of the `htmlPage` variable?

Comment: @AsadAli, I updated my question above. I believe that now you should be able to easily reproduce the issue at stake. Please, let me know if you need me to provide anything else to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may please set PDF Page Margins by using `HtmlLoadOptions.PageInfo.Margin` Property. Following code snippet generates a PDF document that has page margins set and text stamp does not overlap the remaining content of the page.

```
StringBuilder htmlPage = new StringBuilder();
htmlPage.Append(File.ReadAllText(dataDir + "foo.html"));
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlPage.ToString());
var streamHtml = new MemoryStream(bytes);
var objLoadOptions = new Aspose.Pdf.HtmlLoadOptions();
// Set Page Margins
objLoadOptions.PageInfo.Margin = new MarginInfo(50, 50, 50, 50);
// You can also set Page Height/Widht
//objLoadOptions.PageInfo.Height = 898;
//objLoadOptions.PageInfo.Widht = 550;
var doc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(streamHtml, objLoadOptions);

foreach (var page in doc.Pages)
{
 Aspose.Pdf.Facades.FormattedText formattedText = new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.FormattedText(page.Number + "-" + doc.Pages.Count,
                                        new Aspose.Pdf.Facades.FontColor(0, 0, 0) , Aspose.Pdf.Facades.FontStyle.Helvetica, Aspose.Pdf.Facades.EncodingType.Identity_h,
                                        true, 12F);
 var textStamp = new Aspose.Pdf.TextStamp(formattedText)
 {
  VerticalAlignment = Aspose.Pdf.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
  HorizontalAlignment = Aspose.Pdf.HorizontalAlignment.Left,
  LeftMargin = 50,
  BottomMargin = 20
 };
 page.AddStamp(textStamp);
}

doc.Save(dataDir + "out20.1.pdf");
```

You can also specify Page height/width in above code snippet as per your requirements. The related code lines are commented which can be noticed. In case you still face any issue, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your code you add all the margins (top, right, bottom and left). What I need is just a bottom margin. And if you try to add just the bottom margin (`MarginInfo(0, 50, 0, 0)`), then you will see that the bottom margin will be applied only to the first page. Also, I updated what I do after the pages addition. Maybe that causes the issue?

Comment: Are you still there? :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. We have been able to notice the issue that margin was only applied to first page of the PDF document when specified only for bottom. For the sake of correction, we have logged it as PDFNET-47564 in our issue tracking system. We will surely look into details of it and inform you as soon as it is resolved. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will be waiting for the fix.